# Handling Exception in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-handling, try-except

I'm trying to run this:

```
try:
    number = int(number)
except ValueError:
    raise InvalidValueError("%s is not a valid base10 number." % number)
```

So, when I set `number = '51651a'`
I'm getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in decbin
    number = int(number)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '51651a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(decbin('51651a', True))
  File "test.py", line 18, in decbin
    raise InvalidValueError("%s is not a valid base10 number." % number)
__main__.InvalidValueError: 51651a is not a valid base10 number.
```

My question is that is there any way I don't see the line saying, "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"
and all that's above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is disabling Exception Chaining with `from None` [1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exception-chaining).

Change your `raise` statement to

`raise InvalidValueError("%s is not a valid base10 number." % number) from None`

and only your custom exception will be raised, without reference to the ValueError exception originally caught.